# Import Text from span

Tags: javascript, jquery

How get this text via each loop?

```
 $('input[id^="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems2223_repSubElems_ct"]').each(function () { });
```

how get this value?

[image]

This not work

[image]

This also not work
[image]

**Important**

If I will write this I will get this value but underlined part is all the time different

[image]

Comment: $('input[id^="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems2223_repSubElems_ct"]').find("span")  see does it print an object if yes then use .find("span#id")

Comment: html as text would be really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('[id*="hiddenSpanData"]').each(function () { });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var spanText = $('this').next("span#content").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the value content then get element using `find()`

```
$('input[id^="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems2223_repSubElems_ct"]').each(function () { 
   var text = $(this.value).find('span#content').text();
});
```

Comment: I get a lot of elements but not text

Comment: I checked but does not helped. I also updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the span in html you have in input type hidden. So first get the html using .val() on hidden field. After that you can get the span. You can assign html to some div to find span in its descendants.

```
$('<div></div>').text($('input[id^="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_subElems2223_repSubElems_ct"]')
.val()).find('span').eq(1).text();
```

Comment: Share us the html as text instead of image

Comment: I can't Share because this website is via VPN. I try all things to get this value from span

Comment: You can put the html in some file and download it if you can not copy using clipboard